# Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/googlemaps/MainActivity; (1197)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

here,i want to first check that gps is enable or not and if gps is enable then show user location on google maps, checking gps enable or not working fine but it is not opening google map's class their is some problem in MainActivity class..here is my code

Gpsactivator.java

```
package com.example.googlemaps;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;

public class Gpsactivator extends Activity {

    Boolean enable = false;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    int x = 0;
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mapController;

    //Provider gpsprovider;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
         String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    //  gpsprovider=LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Enabled in your devide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
        }else
        {

            showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
            new ultimate().execute("");
            //Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is now Enabled in your devide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


//          
    //  ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Gpsactivator.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
//          while(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
//      {
//          Log.e("TAG",status.toString() );
//          if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
//          {
//              startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
//      //      dialog.dismiss();
//              break;
//          }
//      }
        }

    }

    private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser(){
    //  Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled your Gps and restart your app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GPS is disabled in your device. Would you like to enable it?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Goto Settings Page To Enable GPS",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
        Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
        }
        }
        );
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
        dialog.cancel();
        }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();

        }


    private class ultimate extends AsyncTask<String,Void ,Integer> {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Boolean status=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            Log.e("TAAAG",status.toString()+"1" );
            while(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            {
                Log.e("TAG",status.toString() );
                if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
                {

                    startActivity(new Intent(Gpsactivator.this,MainActivity.class));
            //      dialog.dismiss();
                    break;
                }
            }
      return null;
        }



      }
@Override   
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();


    }





}
```

Mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.googlemaps;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

//public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
//  
//  
//  private GoogleMap mMap;
//  
//
//    @Override
//    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//    
//      //  mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
//        setUpMapIfNeeded();
//  }
//    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
//        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
//        if (mMap == null) {
//          mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
//            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
//            if (mMap != null) {
//                // The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map.
//
//            }
//        }
//    }
//}

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mapController;

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

        locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            0, 
            0, 
            locationListener);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        // enable Street view by default
        mapView.setStreetView(true);

        // enable to show Satellite view
        // mapView.setSatellite(true);

        // enable to show Traffic on map
        // mapView.setTraffic(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(16); 
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener 
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                        (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

                /* Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + 
                        " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                mapController.animateTo(point);
                mapController.setZoom(16);

                // add marker
                MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
                mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
                List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                listOfOverlays.clear();
                listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

                String address = ConvertPointToLocation(point);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                mapView.invalidate();
            }
        }

        public String ConvertPointToLocation(GeoPoint point) {   
            String address = "";
            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
                    getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                    point.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
                    point.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    for (int index = 0; index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
                        address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

            return address;
        } 

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }

    class MapOverlay extends Overlay
    {
        private GeoPoint pointToDraw;

        public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
            pointToDraw = point;
        }

        public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
            return pointToDraw;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

            // convert point to pixels
            Point screenPts = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, screenPts);

            // add marker
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 24, null); // 24 is the height of image        
            return true;
        }
    } 
}
```

Log file

```
07-26 17:20:18.145: W/dalvikvm(15108): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/googlemaps/MainActivity; (1197)
07-26 17:20:18.145: W/dalvikvm(15108): Link of class 'Lcom/example/googlemaps/MainActivity;' failed
07-26 17:20:18.145: E/dalvikvm(15108): Could not find class 'com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity', referenced from method com.example.googlemaps.Gpsactivator.onCreate
07-26 17:20:18.145: W/dalvikvm(15108): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 591 (Lcom/example/googlemaps/MainActivity;) in Lcom/example/googlemaps/Gpsactivator;
07-26 17:20:18.145: D/dalvikvm(15108): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0033
07-26 17:20:18.145: D/dalvikvm(15108): VFY: dead code 0x0035-003a in Lcom/example/googlemaps/Gpsactivator;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
07-26 17:20:18.145: I/ApplicationPackageManager(15108): cscCountry is not German : INS
07-26 17:20:19.036: D/AndroidRuntime(15108): Shutting down VM
07-26 17:20:19.036: W/dalvikvm(15108): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
07-26 17:20:19.731: E/AndroidRuntime(15108): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 17:20:19.731: E/AndroidRuntime(15108): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity
07-26 17:20:19.731: E/AndroidRuntime(15108):    at com.example.googlemaps.Gpsactivator.onCreate(Gpsactivator.java:37)
07-26 17:20:19.731: E/AndroidRuntime(15108):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-26 17:20:19.731: E/AndroidRuntime(15108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
07-26 17:20:19.731: E/AndroidRuntime(15108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
07-26 17:20:19.731: E/AndroidRuntime(15108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-26 17:20:19.731: E/AndroidRuntime(15108):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
07-26 17:20:19.731: E/AndroidRuntime(15108):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 17:20:19.731: E/AndroidRuntime(15108):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-26 17:20:19.731: E/AndroidRuntime(15108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-26 17:20:19.731: E/AndroidRuntime(15108):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 17:20:19.731: E/AndroidRuntime(15108):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-26 17:20:19.731: E/AndroidRuntime(15108):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-26 17:20:19.731: E/AndroidRuntime(15108):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
07-26 17:20:19.731: E/AndroidRuntime(15108):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: could you cut down your code to the relevant part.

Comment: Looks like your using map api v1 which is deprecated use map api v2.

Comment: no i m using map api v2

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/. you should use map api v2 is what i am suggesting.https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/. api v1 is deprecated. And also cut down your code to the relevant part. do not post everything.

Comment: no actually i m using map api v2